# 2D array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

How can I do the indexing of some arrays used as indices? I have the following 2D array like this:

```
array([
   [2, 0],
   [3, 0],
   [3, 1],
   [5, 0],
   [5, 1],
   [5, 2]
])
```

I want to use this array as indices and put the value 10 in the corresponding indices of a new empty matrix. The output should look like this:

```
array([
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [10,  0,  0],
   [10, 10,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0],
   [10, 10, 10]
])
```

So far I have tried this-

```py
from numpy import*
a = array([[2,0],[3,0],[3,1],[5,0],[5,1],[5,2]])
b = zeros((6,3), dtype ='int32')
b[a] = 10
```

But this gives me the wrong output.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: a = np.array([[2,0],[3,0],[3,1],[5,0],[5,1],[5,2]])
In [3]: b = np.zeros((6,3), dtype='int32')

In [4]: b[a[:,0], a[:,1]] = 10

In [5]: b
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [10,  0,  0],
       [10, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

---

**Why it works:**

If you index `b` with *two* numpy arrays in an assignment,

```
b[x, y] = z
```

then think of NumPy as moving simultaneously over each element of `x` and each element of `y` and each element of `z` (let's call them `xval`, `yval` and `zval`), and assigning to b[xval, yval] the value `zval`. When `z` is a constant, "moving over `z` just returns the same value each time.

That's what we want, with `x` being the first column of `a` and `y` being the second column of `a`. Thus, choose `x = a[:, 0]`, and `y = a[:, 1]`.

```
b[a[:,0], a[:,1]] = 10
```

---

**Why `b[a] = 10` does not work**

When you write `b[a]`, think of NumPy as creating a new array by moving over each element of `a`, (let's call each one `idx`) and placing in the new array the value of `b[idx]` at the location of `idx` in `a`.

`idx` is a value in `a`. So it is an int32.  `b` is of shape (6,3), so `b[idx]` is a row of `b` of shape (3,). For example, when `idx` is

```
In [37]: a[1,1]
Out[37]: 0
```

`b[a[1,1]]` is

```
In [38]: b[a[1,1]]
Out[38]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

So

```
In [33]: b[a].shape
Out[33]: (6, 2, 3)
```

So let's repeat: NumPy is creating a new array by moving over each element of `a` and placing in the new array the value of `b[idx]` at the location of `idx` in `a`. As `idx` moves over `a`, an array of shape (6,2) would be created. But since `b[idx]` is itself of shape (3,), at each location in the (6,2)-shaped array, a (3,)-shaped value is being placed. The result is an array of shape (6,2,3).

Now, when you make an assignment like

```
b[a] = 10
```

a temporary array of shape (6,2,3) with values `b[a]` is created, then the assignment is performed. Since 10 is a constant, this assignment places the value 10 at each location in the (6,2,3)-shaped array.
Then the values from the temporary array are reassigned back to `b`.
See [reference to docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays). Thus the values in the (6,2,3)-shaped array are copied back to the (6,3)-shaped `b` array. Values overwrite each other. But the main point is you do not obtain the assignments you desire.

Comment: thanks for explaining this and the insights. but truth be told b[a] is very natural and it's a shame the designers of numpy did not have the foresight to implement it that way.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR: Use advanced indexing: `b[*a.T] = 10`

You can also transpose the index array `a`, convert the result into a tuple and index the array `b` and assign a value. Converting the index array into a tuple (or unpacking it inside a `[]`) ensures that multidimensional indexing works as expected. This is assignment by [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

```py
a = np.array([[2, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2]])
b = np.zeros((6,3), dtype ='int32')

b[*a.T] = 10
# or
b[tuple(a.T)] = 10
# or 
b[(*a.T,)] = 10
# or 
b[(*a.T.tolist(),)] = 10
```

All of them produce the expected output of

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [10,  0,  0],
       [10, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```