# Multidimensional arrays, using range, while simultaneously having a set start, stop, and step?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Oy mates,

I am learning numpy on my own and getting a pretty good handle on it, a few concepts elude me even after reading the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) though. I am trying to go through this matrix and make every second row have 10s all the way through it.

```
data = np.ones(50).reshape(5,10)
xmax = data.shape[0]
ymax = data.shape[1]
data[range(xmax)::2,range(ymax)] = 10
```

The last line of code is incorrect. I know how to use slicing by using semi colons - `list[start:stop:step]` and I know how to use fancy indexing to go through matrices by using commas `ndarray[range(end1),range(end2)]` but how do I combine these two methods?

How do I step through a multidimensional array, using range, while simultaneously having a set start, stop, and step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
>>> data[range(xmax)[::2],:] = 10
>>> data
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.]])'
```

The issue is here:

```
 >>> range(xmax)::
       File "<stdin>", line 1
        range(xmax)::
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You need to apply the slice syntax to the range explicitly:

```
 >>> range(xmax)[::2]
 [0, 2, 4]
```

For general reference you can do:

```
data[np.arange(start1, end1, step1), np.arange(start2, end2, step2)]
```

Where the first `np.arange` chooses the rows and the second `np.aranage` chooses the columns.

**A few references that may help:**

- [Numpy Array
  Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
- [Tentative Numpy Tutorial: Slicing](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)
- [Scipy Lecture Notes : Slicing](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexing-and-slicing)
- [A SO answer by @unutubu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396141/2d-array-indexing)

Comment: Great, I understand completely now. Thanks!

That doesn't seem to explain this type of thing though:
any_data[range(xmax-1,-1,-1), range(ymax)] = 0

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 That would just invert the rows- you can do something similar and more efficiently like so `data[::-1]`.