# Substitute elements of a matrix at specific coordinates in python

Tags: python, performance, substitution, submatrix

I am trying to solve a "very simple" problem. Not so simple in Python. Given a large matrix A and another smaller matrix B I want to substitute certain elements of A with B. 
In Matlab is would look like this:

```
Given A, row_coord = [1,5,6] col_coord = [2,4], and a matrix B of size(3X2), A[row_coord, col_coord] = B
```

In Python I tried to use `product(row_coord, col_coord)` from the `itertools` to generate the set of all indexes that need to be accessible in A but it does not work. All examples on submatrix substitution refer to block-wise row_coord = col_coord examples. Nothing concrete except for the http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/11912 seems to relate to the problem that I am facing and the code in the link does not work.

Note: I know that I can implement what I need via the double for-loop, but on my data such a loop adds 9 secs to the run of one iteration and I am looking for a faster way to implement this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some example matrices and vectors? They don't have to be insanely large, just enough to test with.

Comment: Yes, of course: A = np.zeros([20,20]) col_coord = [0,1,3]  row_coord = [1,2] B = 1 (Let's set B to be constant). The trivial way to solve the problem is by: for a in row_coord: for b in col_coord: A[row_coord[a],col_coord[b]] = 1 but I would like to make it faster by using somehow the intertools utility... Thanks in advance :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `numpy` arrays then (in the case where your `B` is a scalar) the following code should work to assign the chosen elements to the value of `B`.

`itertools.product` will create all of the coordinate pairs which we then convert into a `numpy` array and use in indexing your original array:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

A = np.zeros([20,20])

col_coord = [0,1,3] 
row_coord = [1,2] 

coords = np.array(list(product(row_coord, col_coord)))

B = 1

A[coords[:,0], coords[:,1]] = B
```

I used [this excellent answer by unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16396203/3005188) to work out how to do the indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just as needed. I used the A[product(row_coord, col_coord)] directly without casting into the list and np.array and it gave me    Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: index must be either an int or a sequence