# How to Perform 2d indexing, gather In Pytorch?

Tags: python, indexing, nlp, pytorch

**Use case:**

I am writing beam search submodule in an NLP program which requires 2d indexing for my imlementation.
The setup is:

- `k_next_words` is shape `(batch_size, d1, d2) = (4,5,6)`
- `ix` is shape `(batch_size, k_num_to_select, ix_dim=2) = (4,7,2)`,
  where the `4` dim is batch size, the `7` dim is number of samples to look up, and the `2` dim is a 2d index corresponding to `d1` and `d2` in `k_next_words` (such that the first entry in the index is between 0 and 4 and the second entry is between 0 and 5).

Problem: We want to, for each of the 4 batches gather the 7 entries corresponding to the elements of `k_next_words` at the 2d index.

This is probably a use case for gather, but I haven’t gotten it to work so far!

**Example:**

Here is a toy example to illustrate my use case. Let's ignore the batch size (=4) for now.

`k_next_words` is a torch.Tensor of size (5,6) which looks like:

```
[[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46]]
```

`ix` is a `(7,2)` tensor of coordinates we want to look up in `k_next_words`. As you can see, the first entry in the last dimension is always between 0-4 and the second entry in the last dimension is always between 0-5

```
[[4,5],
 [1,0],
 [0,2],
 [2,2],
 [2,1],
 [3,2],
 [1,1]]
```

Given these two inputs, I want to look up the `7` entries of `k_next_words` determined by the indices in `ix` (note: indexing start at 0), that is, in the toy example:

```
[[46],
 [11],
 [3], 
 [23],
 [22],
 [33],
 [12]]
```

However, I want to do the above, but also for a given batch size (=4) in the example.

Comment: I may be missing something, but aren't you trying to gather 28 (7*4) datapoints instead of 56 ? Like you have 2d coordinates to look up for each batch for k_num_to_select ? Anyway, can you provide a small example, with dummy data, just to show what the output would be for a given input ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I updated with an example!

Comment: It seems like the solution to this is the same as that in numpy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396141/python-numpy-2d-array-indexing