# Numpy: use array of indices to replace values in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following two bidimensional arrays:

```
np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.normal(1,11,(5,5))
b = np.random.randint(0,5,(2,2))

print(a)
print(b)
```

What yields this:

```
[[ 18.867799    -5.72932055  -4.80988927 -10.80265484  10.51948392]
 [-24.31692567  20.19292941  -7.37327591   4.50943006  -1.74307413]
 [ 17.08318731 -21.6615478   -2.54658924  -3.2245979   13.47146387]
 [-11.09880394  -0.89671028  -8.6564426    1.46435121   7.41096735]
 [-11.10681095  13.59196081  10.91749793   6.52743773  10.90941544]]

[[2 1]
 [0 1]]
```

Now imagine that each row in `b` contains the indices `(num_row, num_column)` of values that I want to change in `a` to `0.`, like this:

```
[[ 18.867799     0.          -4.80988927 -10.80265484  10.51948392]
 [-24.31692567  20.19292941  -7.37327591   4.50943006  -1.74307413]
 [ 17.08318731   0.          -2.54658924  -3.2245979   13.47146387]
 [-11.09880394  -0.89671028  -8.6564426    1.46435121   7.41096735]
 [-11.10681095  13.59196081  10.91749793   6.52743773  10.90941544]]
```

What expression should I use to get the previous result? Thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy 2D array indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396141/python-numpy-2d-array-indexing) i.e., `a[b[:, 0], b[:, 1]] = 0` in your case.

Comment: Maybe someone will find a way without an explicit loop, but as a simple (but maybe not optimal) solution, `for p in b: a[tuple(p)] = 0`

Comment: Okay, the first solution (which I saw after posting my comment) should be faster. Thank you @MustafaAydın

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the sexiest answer but if it doesn't have to be fast you could use a vanilla `for` loop

```
for i in b:
    a[i[0], i[1]] = 0
```

Comment: I'm working with large arrays, so I prefer to avoid loops and vectorize as much as I can